# Error Loading WSDL in SOAPUI [****..XML.xsd]: FileNotFoundException

Tags: xml, wsdl, soapui

When you load some of the WSDL files provided by external service vendors, you might encounter this error

Error Loading [****..**XML.xsd**]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified

Error Loading [****..**XMLSchema.dtd**]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified

Not matter you search you will not be able to find thew xml.xsd declaration anywhere in the WSDL file. You wil not get a satisfying response from the service vendor too.

Answer (score 2):

I found it out, its a kind of standard XSD and DTD that the WSDL seeks to find in the directory where the WSDL is placed. This cannot be solved by WSDL vendors or service providers if they are not actually knowing the issue. Happy part is it is **SOLVABLE**

Download the xml.xsd from
https://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd

Donwload the XMLSchema.dtd from 
https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd

Place both these files in the same directory of the WSDL file. Taadaaaa.. the error disappears.